# Replacing url by a value taking from the url with another url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a markdown text file with links like that:

```html
[Text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/unique-doc-id-here/edit)
 
or    

[Text2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/unique-doc-id-here")
```

I want to replace the whole `href` with another one by taking the `unique-doc-id-here`, passing that to a function that will return a new href, so in result my urls would look something like that:

```html
[Text](https://new-url-here.com/fragment-unique-id)

or

[Text2](https://new-url-here.com/fragment-unique-id)
```

I think my problem is to select the `unique-doc-id-here`, I think I have to use the regex for that.

So the solution could be looking like this:

```js
text.replace(/https:\/\/docs.google.com\/document\/d\/(.*?)*/gm, (x) =>
  this.getNewHref(x)
);
```

However it seems that the regex does not looks quite right, because it does not much all the cases. Any ideas how to fix?

Here is an input text example:

```
# Title


Text text text.


Text 1 text 1 text 1, abc.


More text

Bullet points


 - [abc]
 - [bla] 
 - [cba]

## Title 2


More text:


 - A
 - B
 - C
 - D


    Text text text text [url1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/2x2my-DRqfSidOsdve4m9bF_eEOJ7RqIWP7tk7PM4qEr) text.
    
    
    **BOLD.**
    
    
    ## Title 
    
    Text2 text1 text3 text 

[url2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/4x2mrhsqfGSidOsdve4m9bb_wEOJ7RqsWP7tk7PMPqEb/edit#bookmark=id.mbnek2bdkj8c) text.
    
    More text here
    
    
    [bla](https://docs.google.com/document/d/6an7_b4Mb0OdxNZdfD3KedfvFtdf2OeGzG40ztfDhi5o9uU/edit)
```

I've try this regex `\w+:\/\/.*?(?=\s)` but it does select the last `)` symbol

---

I've applied a proposed solution by `@The fourth bird`:

```
function getNewHref(id: string) {
    const data = getText();

    const element = data.find((x: any) => x.id === id);

    if(element?.url) {
      return element.url;
    } else {
      return 'unknown-url'      
    }
  }
```

---

```
data = data.replace(
          /\[[^\][]*]\(https?:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/document\/d\/([^\s\\\/)]+)[^\s)]*\)/gm,
          (x, g1) => getNewHref(g1)
        );
```

The problem is that the replace function replace the whole thing so what was `[...](...)` becomes `./new-url` or `unknown-url` but needs to me `[original text](new result)`

Comment: What happens to the URL with the trailing `/edit`? Should it also be selected, or not? p/s: You might need to escape the `.` character in your pattern

Comment: Do you have actual HTML in your Markdown file or are the links using Markdown syntax, ie `[Text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/unique-doc-id-here)`?

Comment: @Terry I wan't to replace the whole href value

Comment: just added a text example

Comment: Can you explain what examples your regex does not work for?

Comment: @NeithanMax it just does select everything before the docId here is an example https://regex101.com/r/BzLZci/1

Comment: @sreginogemoh Can't help you myself right now. Maybe this can help: https://www.autoregex.xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the pattern more specific, and then use the group 1 value.

```
(\[[^\][]*]\()https?:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/document\/d\/([^\s\\\/)]+)[^\s)]*\)
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `(\[[^\][]*]\()` Capture **group 1**, match from `[...](` using a negated character class
- `https?:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/document\/d\/` Match the leading part of the url
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^\s\\\/)]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char, `\` or `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^\s)]*` Match optional chars other than a whitespace char or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TndycZ/1)

For example, a happy case scenario where all the keys to be replaced exist (note that you can omit the `/m` flag as there are no anchors in the pattern)

```js
const text = "[Text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/unique-doc-id-here/edit)";
const regex = /(\[[^\][]*]\()https?:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/document\/d\/([^\s\\\/)]+)[^\s)]*\)/g;

function getNewHref(id) {
  const replacements = {
    "unique-doc-id-here": `https://docs.google.com/document/d/${id}`
  }

  return replacements[id];
}

const replacedText = text.replace(regex, (x, g1, g2) => g1 + getNewHref(g2)) + ")";

console.log(replacedText);
```

Comment: I believe it does miss one unescaped delimiter, but it works once I fixed that `\[[^\][]*]\(https?:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/document\/d\/([^\s\\\/)]+)[^\s)]*\)`

Comment: @sreginogemoh Ok, that will also exclude matching a backslash in that case.

Comment: I've just got an error on this one so had to fix this way

Comment: @sreginogemoh I have added a code example, I hope it is helpful.

Comment: would you mind to look into the updated question, there is one small issue when replacing an actual string

Comment: @sreginogemoh You can use for example 3 capture groups if you want to keep the leading and trailing parts, see https://regex101.com/r/r0X6Ok/1 Then you have 3 groups in for the replacement function `(x, g1, g2, g3) => getNewHref(g1, g2, g3)` and you can assemble your replacement url using the groups, and capture group 2 contains the `unique-doc-id`

Comment: @sreginogemoh If supported, you can also use a lookbehind assertion and get the match only, see https://regex101.com/r/SoActY/1 In that case, you don't have capture groups. The match for the replacement could be like `x => getNewHref(x)`

Comment: I want to replace the whole thing which is within `(....)` but keeping the `[...]` part e.g `[Url Text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/docId...)` becomes `[Url Text](new-url-from-getNewHref()-here)`, sorry if it wasn't clear. So may be the first group suld be `[Url Text]`, and hen I can wrap the `getNewHref()` result with `()`, if you see what I mean

Comment: so the problem now is that I am currently loosing the `[Url Text]` of input text completely

Comment: I am thinking this `(\[[^\][]*])\((https?:\/\/docs\.google\.com\/document\/d\/)([^\s\\\/)]+)([^\s)]*\))` https://regex101.com/r/Uz9up8/1, what do you think?

Comment: @sreginogemoh I have updated the code example, now you have 2 capture groups. 1 For the leading `[...](` that you want to keep, and another group for the id that you want to capture from the url.

Comment: @sreginogemoh You can also do that with an extra capture group, if you also want to keep the part of the url in the replacement. But if you want to replace the whole parts between `(.....)` then you only need the `unique-id` which you will put in the new url...which you would then put in between the parenthesis.

Comment: aha i c, this one seems better then the one I ended up, with, however getting `pattern error` in `SUBSTITUTION` I want to use that https://regex101.com/r/yruLxn/1

Comment: @sreginogemoh That is because now there are 2 capture groups instead of three, so `$3` would be `$2` https://regex101.com/r/K5YKSq/1

Comment: does it looks good to you that the last `)` becomes a pert of the group like `/edit)` or `/edit#bookmark=id.mbnek2bdkj8c)` ?

Comment: @sreginogemoh If you match the `)`  (not capture) and you want to keep it in the final replacement, you would have to append it again or else it will not be there. If you capture the `)` in a group, then you can append that group again for the final replacement. You can see how many capture groups you have in the regex101 link. Then you have those groups in the replacement callback like `(x, group1, group2, ..etc) =>`

Comment: Yeah I understand, currently I got g1: `[Url Text] (`, g2: `id`, so I had to add up the closing `)` by hand, does it seems right?

Comment: ok thank you for your help, that was the most hard regex manipulation I've ever dealt with

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by getting the `href` link from a string by using `RegEx` and then by splitting that up using forward slash.

Try this (Descriptive comments has been added in the below code snippet) **:**

```js
const text = '<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/unique-doc-id-here/edit">Text</a>';

// Get the href link using regex
const link = text.match(/"([^"]*)"/)[1];

// Split the string and get the array of link based on the forward slash.
const linkArr = link.split('/')

// get the unique ID from an array.
const uniqueID = linkArr[linkArr.indexOf('d') + 1]

console.log(uniqueID);
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, I just added a text example as being requested by someone. I will test and let you know

Comment: oh, i believe that I will edit a question more, because I was wrong about a href, it it is a markdown doc, so there is []() instead of a href. I hope it does make sense